# Storing Values from an Excel File and storing the same into Remote MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, import

I am developing a C# Desktop Application where I want to store values stored in an Excel file to a Remote MySql Database.

Early help will really be Appreciated.

Thanks, and Regards
Rohit Sharma, The Webgrapghica

Need guidance to solve the issue.

Comment: It is the same as if the database were local, except the connection string would point to the remote server. Of course, there are networking considerations like having a route through the internet, the correct port being open, etc., but these are not coding issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Crowcoder . This issue of mine is to develop a code for doing the same.